# Create variable based on other variable outside function

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I'm trying to make my code general, I'd only want to change the YEAR variable without having to change everything in the code

```
YEAR = 1970

y <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:5))

function (y){
  summarize(column_YEAR = sum(col1))
}
#Right now this gives
  column_YEAR
1          15

#I would like this function to output this (so col1 is changed to column_1970)
  column_1970
1          15
```

or for example this

```
df <- list("a_YEAR" = anotherdf)
#I would like to have a list with a df with the name a_1970
```

I tried things like

```
df <- list(assign(paste0(a_, YEAR), anotherdf))
```

But it does not work, does somebody have any advice? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what does your input look like and what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @D.J editted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rlang`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html) provides a flexible way to [defuse R expressions](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html). You can use that functionality to create dynamic column names within `dplyr` flow. In this example dynamic column name is created using `suffix` argument passed to a wrapper function on `dplyr`'s summarise.

```
library("tidyverse")

YEAR = 1970

y <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:5))

function (y) {
  summarize(column_YEAR = sum(col1))
}

my_summarise <- function(.data, suffix, sum_col) {
  var_name <- paste0("column_", suffix)
  
  summarise(.data,
            {{var_name}} := sum({{sum_col}}))
}

my_summarise(.data = y, suffix = YEAR, sum_col = col1)
```

## Results

```
my_summarise(.data = y, suffix = YEAR, sum_col = col1)
#   column_1970
# 1          15
```

---

You can also source arguments directly from global environment but from readability perspective this is poorer solution as it's not immediately clear how the function creates suffix.

```
my_summarise_two <- function(.data, sum_col) {
    
    var_name <- paste0("column_", YEAR)
    
    summarise(.data,
              {{var_name}} := sum({{sum_col}}))
}

my_summarise_two(.data = y, sum_col = col1)
```